# Interdependent tables

Tags: java, database, jpa, spring-data-jpa, h2

I am working on a project with Java, Spring Boot, JPA and H2 database.
However, I am confused with how the database tables have been designed.
There are 3 tables A,B and C.

Table A has Table B's primary key as foreign key.

Table B has Table C's primary key as foreign key.

Table C has Table A's primary key as foreign key.
Since each table is dependent on other tables, when I am creating the schema of all the three I am getting an error indicating Table B is not found

I have even tried using ALTER commands but still facing the same issue.

Here is my code

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TEAMS;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TEAMS (
  `team_id` int (11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar (100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `train_id` int (11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`team_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_teams_trains` FOREIGN KEY (`train_id`) REFERENCES TRAINS (`train_id`)
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS USERS;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS USERS (
  `user_id` int (11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `team_id` int (11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `reports_to` int (11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_users_teams` FOREIGN KEY (`team_id`) REFERENCES TEAMS (`team_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_users_users` FOREIGN KEY (`reports_to`) REFERENCES USERS (`user_id`)
);


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TRAINS;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TRAINS` (
  train_id INT (11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  train_name varchar (100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  team_coach INT (11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  train_vp INT (11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`train_id`)
);

 ALTER TABLE TRAINS ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_trains_users` FOREIGN KEY (`team_coach`) REFERENCES USERS (`user_id`);
 ALTER TABLE TRAINS ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_trains_users_2` FOREIGN KEY (`train_vp`) REFERENCES USERS (`user_id`);
 ALTER TABLE TEAMS ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_teams_trains` FOREIGN KEY (`train_id`) REFERENCES TRAINS (`train_id`);
 ALTER TABLE USERS ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_users_teams` FOREIGN KEY (`team_id`) REFERENCES TEAMS (`team_id`);
 ALTER TABLE USERS ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_users_users` FOREIGN KEY (`reports_to`) REFERENCES USERS (`user_id`);
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: looks like you do not ned the `CONSTRAINT` lines in your `CREATE TABLE` as you are adding the constraints afterwards in the `ALTER TABLE`

Comment: Create Trains table first then Teams and at the end Users table.

Comment: @ScaryWombat I removied Constraint as you suggested, but when I am trying to insert values to all the 3 tables I am getting something like                **Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Referential integrity constraint violation: "FK_TEAMS_TRAINS: PUBLIC.TEAMS FOREIGN KEY(TRAIN_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.TRAINS(TRAIN_ID) (3)"; SQL statement:**

Comment: @Adeel I already tried changing the order for table creation but still no luck

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @Scary Wombat in the comments, you may remove `CONSTRAINTS` from `CREATE` statements and add them at the end using `ALTER` statements (as you already have)

Here's the updated SQL:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TEAMS;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TEAMS (
  `team_id` int (11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar (100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `train_id` int (11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`team_id`)
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS USERS;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS USERS (
  `user_id` int (11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `team_id` int (11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `reports_to` int (11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
);


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TRAINS;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TRAINS (
  train_id INT (11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  train_name varchar (100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  team_coach INT (11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  train_vp INT (11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`train_id`)
);

ALTER TABLE TRAINS ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_trains_users` FOREIGN KEY (`team_coach`) REFERENCES USERS (`user_id`);
ALTER TABLE TRAINS ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_trains_users_2` FOREIGN KEY (`train_vp`) REFERENCES USERS (`user_id`);
ALTER TABLE TEAMS ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_teams_trains` FOREIGN KEY (`train_id`) REFERENCES TRAINS (`train_id`);
ALTER TABLE USERS ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_users_teams` FOREIGN KEY (`team_id`) REFERENCES TEAMS (`team_id`);
ALTER TABLE USERS ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_users_users` FOREIGN KEY (`reports_to`) REFERENCES USERS (`user_id`);
```